# How Are The Graphs Related?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

We had this as a bonus question on my discrete math exam, and I have absolutely no idea how to even begin a question like this. Can someone explain this question to me, in case I see it as a bonus question again?

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function, let c be a real number , and define $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x) = x - c$. Explain how the graphs of $f $and $f \circ g$ are related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

It just moves it to the right by $c$ units.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, but what if c < 0 ?

Comment: @JebusCrust Then it moves to the left by $c$ units.

Comment: then it moves it to the left $-c$ units. You can also interpret it as translating the graph by the vector $(c,0)$.

Comment: Okay. Just to be 100% sure, it c = 0, the graphs would just be the same?

Comment: yeah, because then $g(x)=x$ and so $f(g(x))=f(x)$.